# Can we convert polar to rectangular when we are given $(1,\theta )$ where $ r=1$ and $0\le \theta <2\pi $?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Can we convert polar to rectangular when we are given $(1,\theta )$ where  $ r=1$ and $0\le \theta <2\pi $?

Comment: what you mean with "rectangular"? You mean "cartesian" instead?

Comment: Yes. To cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt plot it.  It might help you see the answer.

The basic rules for converting between caretesian and polar.

$x = r \cos \theta\\
y = r \sin \theta$

$\theta = \tan^{-1} (\frac yx)\\
r =  \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

So what do you know?

$r = 1.$  What does that mean for $(x,y)$?

Comment: I know that x^2+y^2 =1 and that's the graph of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

$(r, \theta) = (1, \theta)$ geometrically means that the distance from the origin is [constant] 1, and the angle can vary freely. One particular shape should come to mind. Or as Doug M points out, in this case you obtain a familiar parametrisation $(x,y) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

Comment: So, I know that r = 1 = x^2+y^2 which is the graph of a circle.

Comment: I am confused because I do not understand how to convert a function in polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates.  U(1,theta) = 10+3sin(theta)-10cos(2*theta)